# How to include three different tables data in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, join

```
(columns name)
b_Users = id,users_id,ac_num,bills
r_Users = id,users_id,ac_num,bills

f_users = id,users_id,name,address

f_users table:
id ----users_id---- name ---- address
1         12/1      A         ad1
2         13/2      B         ad2
3         14/1      C         ad3

b_Users table: 
id ---- users_id ---- ac_num ---- bills
1       12/1           1234         10$
2       14/1           1235         12$

r_Users table:     
id ---- users_id ---- ac_num ---- bills
1       13/2           1238         19$
```

I want to select (users_id,name,address,ac_num,bills)

I used Join but there's showing empty fields. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd query a `union all` between `b_users` and `r_users` and then join `users` on it:

```
SELECT f.users_id, name, address, ac_num, bills
FROM   (SELECT b.users_id, ac_num, bills
        FROM   b_users b
        UNION ALL
        SELECT r.users_id, ac_num, bills
        FROM   r_users r) t
JOIN  f_users f on f.users_id = t.users_id
```

Comment: @ArafHossain shouldn't, but to be on the safe side, I edited the select list to qualify it.

Comment: I edited the que, Now I think You will better understand. @Mureinik

Comment: @ArafHossain having the right tables in the question helps. Try now.

Comment: pardon me for this. By the query is soo big for this reason I describe it normally. in here. Let me check is it working or not.

Comment: bro can you please help to search Bangla language in the search field @mureinik